# install forever without internet

Tags: node.js, forever

hi I have tried to install forever in a machine without internet. I have download the folder forever-master from https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever. I put it on /tmp. My npm -v is: 1.1.61; and node -v: v0.8.9. Then, I did: npm install forever-master -g but after some minutes I got:

..........................................................................
..........................................................................

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/0.1.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston/0.7.1
npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo EADDRINFO
npm ERR! at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
npm ERR! at Object.onanswer as oncomplete
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.26-2-686
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever-master" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /tmp
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.61
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code EADDRINFO
npm ERR! errno EADDRINFO
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /tmp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I think npm tried to do  an external connection.................? 
Is it not possible to install forever using the forever-master folder without a internet connection? if oui, what did I do wrong?thanks

Comment: Did you `cd` into the downloaded folder and run `npm install . -g`? Also it seems like npm is trying to fetch forever's dependencies.

Comment: I have done npm install . -g and the error is the same....

Comment: do you got the answer..? I'm also having the same problem on my server.

Answer (score 0):

When you npm install, it will go curl the packages from https://registry.npmjs.org. That's what npm does- it goes to the internet. Downloading it from github will not do anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

NPM stands for Node Package Manager, it will fetch a package and all of it's dependencies that are not currently installed in the relevant `./node_modules` from the repositories in the relevant `package.json` files.

I'd hazard a guess if you fetched the entire dependency tree and uploaded this you'd be OK. but it would somewhat defeat the point of having your dependencies managed externally so as you can easily pull in required updates, fixes and features from the required packages and their dependencies.

So in short, it is possible but you can't expect NPM to not do what it is purpose built to do and resolve dependencies in your packages to installable modules.